# Creating your own options-general.php page

Tags: wp-admin, options, settings-api

I wanted to develop a duplicate General Settings Page instead of the built in one and all the settings on the built-in General Settings Page will also be displayed on the new General Settings Page.. the purpose of this is add some codes like inserting some options of a new table. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You don’t. You would have to keep your new page in sync with the core file each time WordPress is updated … that would not be very pragmatic.
Hook into the `do_settings_sections('general');` with [`register_setting()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) and add your code here.

There is a third parameter for `register_setting()`: you can register a callback function here which used before the value is saved to the database.

See the @Otto’s [WordPress Settings API Tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/) for some examples. In one of my own plugins I do the same: [Public Contact Data](https://github.com/toscho/Public-Contact-Data). See the method `function add_contact_fields()` for details.

Comment: I basically want to run a mysql query upon submission of the general settings form.. like inserting the `site title` to a new table.. i want to accomplish this..

Comment: @Ken See my update.

Comment: If I understand correct you only wish to change the site title from the `options-general.php` and from a custom theme options page `themes.php?page=theme_options`? In that case I've recently asked a similar question here: http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/4052 (just about the WP tagline)